# Why does amplitude of a standìng wave on a string vary with frequency?

Tags: waves

I have seen in various simulations and demonstrations that when we connect a stretched string to a harmonic oscillator and gradually increase the frequency, the amplitude of the resulting waveform decreases. What is the reason? Has it anything to do with the total energy in one wavelength expression? Even when we do not increase the frequency gradually, but do separate experiments,  then also this thing is observed.

Comment: The stored energy depends on both the amplitude of the motion and the frequency of the motion.  If the stored energy is constant as the frequency is increased then the amplitude would decrease.

Comment: @Farcher I would like to say that even when we do not gradually increase the frequency, but do separate experiments, then also this thing occurs.

Comment: Please give an example of the simulation or demonstration you're talking about.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you have in mind. I assume the (finite length) string is fixed on one end and driven sinusoidally at the other end.  If so, a standing wave forms only when the driving frequency is one from a discrete set of eigenfrequencies. If the string is initially being driven such that a standing wave forms, and if you slightly change the driving frequency, do you still get a standing wave?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri When the experiment is performed it is found that as a higher harmonic is excited the amplitude of the higher harmonic is not as large as when a lower harmonic is excited.

Comment: @Farcher, it's the OPs prescription to "gradually increase the frequency" that seems to contradict that interpretation.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri So it is the move away for resonance which is being asked about?

Comment: @Farcher, I don't know, it isn't clear to me what the OP has in mind.

Comment: Sorry my wording might be a bit ambiguous (English isn't my first language) but @ Farcher I think has got what i wanted to ask that amplitude of higher harmonic is not as large as the lower harmonics